# how to IIS service start automatically?

Tags: iis-6

Each time when i start my server , i need to go to IIS and then need to start the each web application manually. i want to start all web application automatic as my server starts. You will wonder why I m shuts down my server again and again. But it is test server. so that only. anyway. which service have to make automatic? It is Windows Server 2003. using IIS V6.0

Comment: check the answer now might resolve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the iis service is set to start automatically. For this go to the Services MMC and ensure that the World Wide Web Publishing Service is set to start automatically. If there are no problem with the sites, they should start automatically. Also check here: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30451499/how-to-set-default-web-s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IIS(Microsoft web server) server are mostly installed in windows operating system(OS) ,we want to just start a service only,if iis server not installed then easily download and install in windows. 
For [More Reference](http://gleegrid.com/blog/how-to-install-iis-server-and-start-iis-service/)